# a questtion about UIWebView highlight color

Tags: html, ios, css, uiwebview

I dont kow how to change the webView highlight color, can u help me?

please see the image description!

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want to update the highlight color, you can use :

**This one will apply the color on every element**

```
::-moz-selection { background: red; }
::selection { background: red; }
```

**You can apply the color on one specific element too**

```
p::-moz-selection { background: red; }
p::selection { background: red; }
```

*If you need more information you can check this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/*

```css
::-moz-selection { background: deeppink; }
::selection { background: deeppink; }
```

```html
<h1> Hello Word !</h1>
```

Comment: thanks,i try it by your suggest ,but this method is effective just on safari and IE. In iphone UIWebView it can not work